# From hyperterminal to OS

Tags: hyperterminal

**Is there any way to take data from hyperterminal (whatever it has recevied from COM port) and give it to OS (windows).**
For example, I want to write data which is coming from COM port into Microsoft Word file.

In other words, I've my own keyboard with RS323 interface and I want whatever I type is written in Microsoft Word file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in C# you can use the [SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) class. Here's a tutorial that goes over this: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/SerialPort-brief-Example-ac0d5004

You will not need Hyperterminal for this as your software would do the comms instead using SerialPort.

From there I would use a [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) (or something similar) to export it to a text file. You can try exporting to word but it will probably frustrate you.

Be aware that you set the relevant flowcontrol and baud rate settings that your device will require, otherwise you will experience connection issues.

Comment: Isn't what he want more of a keyboard over RS323 driver?

Comment: Yep, I didn't read the bit about using a keyboard until just now. This still answers his original question though (I think).

Comment: Thanks @ing0. Alxandr is right, that's what i wanted. It should work like a keyboard, like when i press start button on my keyboard, it should open start menu...
Can it be done?

Comment: It can be done, but unfortunately I only have experience writing comms apps and not kb drivers so I don't think I can help you any further, sorry!